# How to restrict CPU, Memory usage to its 80% of total allocation in windows operating system?

Tags: memory, cpu, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

we have multiple application servers, which utilizes 100% of CPU and Memory, is there anyways we can control this usage at OS level, so that it will never go above 80% of its total allocation. Issues with 100%- 1) CPU and Memory staying in 100% usage doesn't allows to do any other operation on server than the running application 2) It always triggers alert for CPU and Memory size increment in our capacity review, but we have already allocated 64 GB of RAM and 16 cores to the VM, but still they are in 100% usage, so it seems application are eating up all the available resources

Here OS is Windows Server 2012 R2, 2016 and 2019 Standard

Requesting you, Please help for any solution at OS level in this situation, and let me know if any further details is needed on this question, before down-voting

Comment: You might want to check out your Services. Stop any you don't need, really, and see if that helps, be careful. Open Task Manager and see what is eating at your memory and CPU.

Comment: @vssher problem is there are multiple services, also multiple applications of different technologies, we work at os level not at app level, this custom app utilizes all the memory and cpu, so want to find a way to stop utilization to 80% of resource only